# Тригер на удаление записи и ее добавление в другую таблицу

Tags: sql, триггер

Пытаюсь написать триггер, который бы срабатывал при удалении записи из таблицы и переносил удаляемое значение в резервную таблицу.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `lands_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `lands` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT history_table_epl(history_text_epl) 
SELECT nameL
FROM lands;
END
```

Собственно, триггер срабатывает, но он переносит вообще все записи из этого столбца таблицы lands, а мне нужно лишь то конкретное значение из столбца nameL, которое я удаляю. Понимаю, что надо добавить какое-то условие в WHERE, но какое - не знаю, поэтому прошу помощи)
Делаю все это в MySQL Workbench.

Структура таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то пригодится:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `lands_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `lands` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT history_table_epl(history_text_epl)  values (OLD.nameL);
END
```